# select field information with min time value

Tags: php, mysql

I thought I was doing the right thing but I keep getting the wrong result. I am trying to simply find the id of the entry with the min time, but I am not getting that entry.

```
$qryuserscount1="SELECT id,min(entry_time) FROM scrusersonline WHERE topic_id='$topic_id'";
$userscount1=mysql_query($qryuserscount1);
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($userscount1)) {
    echo $onlineuser= $row2['id'];
}
```

That is my query, and it does not work. This however does work which does not make sense to me
**SELECT id FROM scrusersonline WHERE topic_id='$topic_id' ORDER by entry_time LIMIT 1**, can anyone quickly point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id,min(entry_time) FROM scrusersonline WHERE topic_id='$topic_id'
```

will return `id` and `entry_time` for every row matching `topic_id`, since there is no group-by clause from which the `min(entry_time)` could be selected. The `SELECT` clause only defines what *columns* are to be returned, it doesn't *restrict* that selection by rows any - that's what the `WHERE` clause is for.

```
SELECT id FROM scrusersonline WHERE topic_id='$topic_id' ORDER BY entry_time LIMIT 1
```

will return `id` (`SELECT id`) for *only the first* (`LIMIT 1`) matching `topic_id` (`WHERE topic_id='$topic_id'`) when ordered by `entry_time` (which is the minimum).

So, yes, `SELECT id FROM scrusersonline WHERE topic_id='$topic_id' ORDER BY entry_time LIMIT 1` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks pinkgothic, appreciate your time

Answer (score 1):

I think that the min function has to be used with a group by clause. However, the second request you post selects the full id list where topic_id is what you want, ordered by entry_time (you could add an ASC or DESC which makes it clearest imo)  and then, returns only the first.

What's wrong with it? :-)

Comment: I just thought maybe min was a more efficient way if I could do it correctly, but apparently that intention is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  id, MIN(entry_time)
FROM    scrusersonline
WHERE   topic_id='$topic_id'
```

According to `SQL` standards, this query is invalid.

You cannot use `id` in the `SELECT` list unless you `GROUP BY` it, since it's not clear which `id` from the group should be returned.

`MySQL`, however, allows such queries which return any random `id` from the group (of from the whole recordset, if there is no `GROUP BY` clause).

This behavior is intended to simplify `PRIMARY KEY` joins with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  mytable.*, COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable
JOIN    othertable
ON      othertable.col1 = mytable.id
GROUP BY
        mytable.id
```

In this case, all records from `mytable` are guaranteed to be the same within the group and it does not matter which one will be returned.

Your query will not return you the record holding the minimal value of `entry_time`. Instead, it will return you the minimal value of `entry_time` and a *random* `id` satisfying the `topic_id = $topic_id` condition which is not guaranteed to belong to the same record.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the informative response Quassnoi. I suppose the second way I showed is my only option then correct?

Comment: @scarface: Yes. It can be made faster if you create a composite index on `(topic_id, entry_time)`.